# when I change model value ,all model value changes?

Tags: list, kotlin

When I change the last value of the model in my list to false, that value changes to false everywhere, I want my value to be true in the first list element and remain false at the end.

How can I solve this problem?

```
mainAccount?.isMainAccount = true
checkedAccountList?.add(mainAccount!!)
mainAccount?.isMainAccount = false
checkedAccountList?.add(mainAccount!!)
```

Comment: `val connectedMainAccount: AccountModel? = mainAccount?.clone()
                connectedMainAccount?.isMainAccount = false
                checkedAccountList?.add(connectedMainAccount!!)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are changing property of same object that is why after third line your both item in list have false as mainAccount value. Take look at below diagram, In this I am trying to show that list item only contain reference to your object.

If you need to have separate value for both item than you must create new object and copy rest of values from first object and change mainAccount value to false.

for ex.

```
        mainAccount?.isMainAccount = true
        checkedAccountList?.add(mainAccount!!)
        Account mainAccount2 = new MainAccount();
        // copy other fields if needed
        mainAccount2?.isMainAccount = false
        checkedAccountList?.add(mainAccount2!!)
```

[image]

Comment: very thanks but I cant solve this problem. 
                `mainAccount?.isMainAccount = true
                checkedAccountList?.add(mainAccount!!)
                val mainAccount2: AccountModel?=mainAccount
                mainAccount2?.isMainAccount = false
                checkedAccountList?.add(mainAccount2!!)`

Comment: You are still doing same thing, you must create new object by invoking constructor call of object.

replace :     val mainAccount2: AccountModel? = mainAccount
with       :     val mainAccount2: AccountModel? = AccountModel() 

if you are using kotlin and using data class for AccountModel than you can use as below

               :     val mainAccount2: AccountModel? = mainAccount!!.copy()